# Access an the same EJB from multiple other EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

So I have an ejb that handles users. I want to access information in this ejb from multiple other EJBs.

I can't use a singleton as that would mean the bean would be shared with all users. Each user should only have one instance of this EJB.

It seems that everywhere I inject the ejb a new instance is created

Simplified example:

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class Producer implements ProducerLocal {

    public User user = null;
    // getter/setters omitted
}

@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class Consumer implements ConsumerLocal {

    @Inject @SessionScoped
    private Producer producer;
    // getter/setters omitted

    // Another similar consumer sets the user in producer
    // Getting the user here raises a null pointer exception
    // Because this has a different instance of the producer

}
```

Comment: Please share some code so that it is easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you looking for Stateless EJBs?

Comment: @MickMnemonic sorry, I added it

Comment: The consumer can be stateless. The producer is stateful.

Comment: Ensure that you have used [javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) and not [javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/SessionScoped.html).

Comment: You cannot have a stateless holding a reference to a stateful. It should be the other way round.

Comment: you could use managed beans for data storing and EJBs for processing (transactions, security)